# Python - best practices for time unit conversions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does python provide support for time unit conversions beyond explicit arithmetic? For example, in Java:

```
TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);     // 1 day to milliseconds.
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(23); // 23 minutes to milliseconds.
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(4);    // 4 hours to milliseconds.
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(96); // 96 seconds to milliseconds.
```

Comment: Python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)` module provides both a `datetime` and `timedelta` class. The `timedelta` class in particular has properties for number of `days`, `seconds`, and `microseconds`, though unfortunately to convert days to milliseconds you would need to actually multiply by `60*60*24*1000`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `dateutil` [library](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) which has a `relativedelta` function that you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module provides both a `datetime` and `timedelta` class. The `timedelta` class, in particular, has properties for number of days, seconds, and microseconds, though unfortunately to convert days to milliseconds you would need to actually multiply by `60*60*24*1000`.